# Best way to automate video production

Tags: audio, video, images, automation

If I have an image, and a 30 second audio file, what is the best way to automatically combine these into a video file suitable for uploading to youtube?

I've got quite a few to make, so doing it manually isn't really an option.

Comment: Undoubtedly you can use **Windows Movie maker** for Windows, you can Google it for Windows 7. And as far you have not mentioned what OS you are using it's hard to determine what kind of software you need.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate. I'm aware of how to do this with free Windows/Apple software. The problem is that I've got 50 of these things to make, so there should be a way of doing this automatically. I have an image, and a mp3. I don't need any fancy effects or transitions. They just need combining these into a video without too much difficulty. Any ideas?

Comment: Windows or Mac.